# Converting number using php or sql

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have spent a lot of google time on this and im not sure about the best way I would need to go about it

I have a small web program that adds number into a database with query that runs on selections, to clear certain information out, these query only succeed if the numbers in a certain column are 13 digits long, why I don't know.

So my question is what is the best way to make the digits in the column in sql autoconvert to 13 using either sql or php  so if i where to type 1 it would end up in the sql column as 0000000000001 instead of 1

The query I have php running is very simple I don't quite understand why it has to have 13

The code is as follow

```
<?php include_once "ewcfg9.php" ?>
<?php include_once "adodb5/adodb.inc.php" ?>
<?php include_once "phpfn9.php" ?>
<?php include_once "Productsinfo.php" ?>
<?php include_once "userfn9.php" ?>
<?php
$upc= $_GET['upc'];
sleep(2);
header('Location: Productsedit2.php?upc='.$upc.'');
$serverName = "localhost";
$usr="sl";
$pwd="o.o";
$db="SimpleLabel";

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false)

{

print_r( sqlsrv_errors());

}

$sql="Delete from labelprint where upc=$upc";

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql) or die(sqlsrv_errors());
$result=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
print_r($result); 
sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

This works but only if the upc=13 digits
so can anyone think if there is a way i can make sql make everything 13 digits or make php autofill the field with 13 digits?

Comment: What is the type of the column in the DB?  Also, you need to be escaping the parameter from $_GET (or better yet, use prepared statements).

Comment: the type is varchar(13) also the way it is the way it is, is it runs the query quickly and pass the variable onto the edit page where the information can be edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the column is a string type, it must be treated as such. (An option would be to use a numeric column and then either pad it in PHP-land, or use zero fill [I think SQL Server has zero fill].)

You should really be using prepared statements, but at the least you need to escape any string you put into an SQL. You might want to look into SQL injection.

---

Anyway, I would use sprintf:

```
$padded = sprintf("%013d", (int) $upc);
```

Then this:

```
$sql="Delete from labelprint where upc=$upc";
```

would become

```
$sql="Delete from labelprint where upc='$padded'";
```

The single quotes are necessary because it's a string, not a number.  The int cast in the sprintf call is so that it's guaranteed that the $padded output will be safe to put into an SQL statement.

---

You could also use a combination of str_repeat and strlen to pad the string.

Comment: I second the notion of looking into SQL injection. I personally use PDO for all my PHP to DB interactions. Even when they are solely on my LAN because I never know when I might want to push a tool/script up to a public server and I only want to maintain one DAO.

Comment: corbin on using your example the query works but does something very odd if there is a item in the db that has 13 digits like it is suppose to and one that does not like for example 1, the 1 will not remove itself but the other will, but if the 13 digit is not in there then the 1 will remove using the query very odd

Comment: gabe tried your edit the query now no longer does anything im looking at the syntac to see if i missed something

Comment: also something else werid, i went into the db and manually added the 0's in the front of the 1 making it equal of total of 13 and it still would not remove with the query, but the 2 items i scanned in with the gun will very confusing

Comment: @quatre432 if the field is a varchar, it has no concept of the data being numeric.  You will have to make sure it exactly matches.  '0001' != '1' for non integral types.  I would probably consider storing the numeric data as numeric.  The only problem with that though might be if UPCs ever have non-numeric characters in them.

Comment: before reading your statement i got to looking at my orginal code, and notice i didnt have '$upc' where i should have had in the query put that in and i dont have to make everything have the 13 0's, tried your correction after an also works thanks cant believe i missed it

Comment: It looks like my edit had a couple of things added to it. The (int) in front of $upc which is good. And the 's around $padded which I didn't put in there. Typically I use PDO and it would be where upc = ? and then you pass in $padded and PDO takes care of casting it correctly for the DB. You might also be able to do "... where upc = " . $padded.

Comment: One last thing, if you are like me you manually tried to add 12 0s in front of that 1 to get 13 chars but actually added 11 or 13 0s and thus the query fails. If the DB isn't too big you might try spinning thru it on a loop and using strlen on all the values to double check they are all 13 chars long. Also cast all of them to (int) and do a $value != (int) $value then fail. Just to see if any fail in case there is an O you think is a 0? I don't know what the integrity of your data is.

Comment: @Gabe yes, I edited your edit.  The `'` are actually necessary if the column is a string type.  A non-string-marked string as the value for a string column is treated as an entity name by default.  That means it would look for a column/function/etc named 0000000000001 (if it didn't see that it was a syntax error first).  It would be the equivalent of trying something like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = gabe`

Answer (score 0):

If the `labelprint` field is an int (in which case, why *are* you storing it as a varchar) you [could cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) it as follows:

```
$sql="Delete from labelprint where cast(upc as unsigned)=$upc";
```

This won't work though if you have funny data in it. eg `0000000000013` will *cast* as `13` but `000000AB00013` will *not* cast as 13.

Edit: SQL-Server Int might be 4 Bytes, but that gives you a range of  -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) (which is clearly *not* 4 numbers)

The change of datatype also makes the answer above pretty redundant.

Comment: im sorry i typoed im storing them as a nvarchar(13) but i will change to a int and try this

Comment: @quatre432 varchar or nvarchar, if you mean it to be an `int` why are you storing it in a string? Store data the way you mean to use it - even if that means changing it to the right data type before you insert it into the database :)

Comment: ok i will try both of your suggestions give me a few minutes to change my code

Comment: Um going to sound dumb if i change the design of the coulmn to a int, i cannot use more that 4, the size of the column need to allow 13, why i was using nvarchar(13)

Comment: @quatre432 Change the datatype to a bigint and you shold be sweet.

Comment: @quatre432 See the edit I made. bigint is 8 *bytes* which does not mean 8 characters. You can stick anywhere between 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 into a bigint.

Comment: ok one promblem i have with using bigint and again im sorry a program i have reads this database with these "upc's" in using big int i loose the leading zeros, i cant have that happen because if there is a barcode associated with it, it will not work properly

Comment: @quatre432 If you have to compare an int against a string, you should look at the answer provided by Corbin. It should work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a string instead of an int for the field, you could try this:

`$upc = str_pad($upc, 13, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

This will padd a string so it is up to 13 chars, using `0` as the 'filler'.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Comment: Thanks for your response your method does something similar to crobins, it works except for if the upc=1 it wont remove it